# Flask custom "not found" code

Tags: python, flask

I want to change the default 404 code, when flask doesn't finds the route, to other code. How can I do that?

Comment: Is the case that you want to change page (or its message) which displayed upon 404 ?

Comment: Why would you want to change the 404 to some other code? If you want to use some more specific code like 410 (Gone) you should only use it for some routes and only if the document was really deleted.

Comment: I am making specific api, 404 used when object is not found, 502 will be used when flask doesn't finds the route

Comment: A 502 means the server received an invalid response. This is a case where a request asked for something that doesn't exist. That's a 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said, it is generally not a good idea to redefine the meaning of standard status codes.

Although you can change a status code returned, here's an example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return 'This page does not exist', 777

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This will return status code 777 on any page other than `/`.

Here's a result:

[image: 777 status code]

More on the topic you can find [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses).

Comment: but if I do abort(404) in the code @app.errorhandler(404) will handle it, and then I'll get 777 instead of 404

Comment: @novox I think that you can use what I posted to change the 404 code to something else. And for _your 404_ you can make a custom exception (see [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/exceptions/#custom-errors) and [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/apierrors/)) and then handle it returning 404 status. You won't be able to use `abort(404)`, at least without modifying flask itself. You will have to `raise YourCustomFourOFour(...)` exception instead of `abort(404)`.

Comment: @novox you are welcome. But still, I would recommend not to mess with standard status codes and just use custom status codes for your custom exceptions/cases.